# how t use 'IF' in 'SELECT' statement with insert on mysql

Tags: mysql

my table is

```
id_stuff | kd_insert | name_stuff | date_createdd 
1        | 1         | example    | 2018-01-01
```

i create the query in mysql like this

```
SELECT IF ((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m') > DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date_createdd),'%Y-%m')), 
(
  INSERT INTO tabless (name_stuff) VALUES ('stuff')
), 
(
 null
)
 ) FROM tabless GROUP BY id_stuff ORDER BY kd_insert
```

after i run, why i get some error like this

> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO tabless (name_stuff) VALUES ('stuff').

and how to create the right `select with condition then insert`?
thanks

Comment: i just want use if the value of Now > date_created then save the nameperson of date_created = name

Comment: why i use `select if then insert` always error 
like the code above there

Comment: no, `date_created` is from my attribut like this

`id_stuff | kd_insert | name_stuff | date_created 
1           | 1              |  example    |   2018-01-01`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to write insert statement like that.
You can do this -

```
SELECT
  if(
    (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')) > DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date_createdd), '%Y-%m'),
    (@value = 'stuff'),
    null
  )
FROM
  tabless
GROUP BY
  id_stuff
ORDER BY
  kd_insert;
INSERT INTO tabless (name_stuff) VALUES ('stuff');
```

Comment: sorry thats its wrong, you just insert data with values is only stuff, you know code `if ( (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')) > DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date_createdd), '%Y-%m'), // this is (true), // or (false) ` because that i create with insert like `INSERT INTO tabless (name_stuff) VALUES ('stuff') // if true` after condition or i can insert, like`INSERT INTO tabless (name_stuff, date_createdd) VALUES (name, date_createdd) // if true get the true of value and insert the data`, that's what i mean, 
but thanks for writing some code

Comment: It will be easy to use in a stored or procedure